# Splitting a dataframe on a specific string value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe which i have to split as soon as a specific string value in a column occurs.
Ex. df =

```
    txn_details amt
0   opening_balance 13000
1   opening_balance 15000
2   upi2873         12879
3   upi182y31   12301
4   opening_balance 85050
5   upi79279831 8400
```

The desired output(3 dataframes)(may vary depending on the no. of occurrences of 'opening_balance'):
df_1 =

```
    txn_details amt
0   opening_balance 13000


df_2 = 
    txn_details amt
0   opening_balance 15000
1   upi2873         12879
2   upi182y31   12301


df_3 = 
    txn_details amt
0   opening_balance 85050
1   upi79279831 8400
```

I've tried using cumsum() function in pandas but not getting the desired output.

Comment: @jezrael oops, I had copied the wrong link

Comment: @jezrael why do you remove my links? This info is interesting for readers...

Comment: @mozway - because not matched?

Comment: sorry, but I believe this has an added values

Answer (score 0):

Compare `opening_balance` with `txn_details` with cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and in dictionary comprehensioncreate dict of DataFrames:

```
d = {f'df_{i}': g.reset_index(drop=True) 
     for i, g in df.groupby(df['txn_details'].eq('opening_balance').cumsum())}

print (d['df_1'])
       txn_details    amt
0  opening_balance  13000
```